# JSON parsing app "no data"?

Tags: android, json, parsing

Here's the code for my JSON parsing app. It force closes as soon as I run it on my emulator. I am new to Android programming, and I'm self taught so please bear with me. Thanks!

JSONfunctions.java:

```
package com.pxr.tutorial.json;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONfunctions {

public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url){
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;

    //http post
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

  //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new            
                InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    try{

        jArray = new JSONObject(result);            
    }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;
}
}
```

Main.java:

```
package com.pxr.tutorial.json;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import com.pxr.tutorial.xmltest.R;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, 
    String>> ();


    JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL
("http://www.tastekid.com/ask/ws?q=mosdef&f=musifin2125&k=mjjlnzkyzwuz&format=JSON");                
    try{

        JSONArray  similar = json.getJSONArray("similar");

        for(int i=0;i<similar.length();i++){                        
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
            JSONObject e = similar.getJSONObject(i);

            map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
            map.put("name", "Name:" + e.getString("name"));
            map.put("type", "Type: " +  e.getString("type"));
            mylist.add(map);            
        }       
    }catch(JSONException e)        {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main, 
                    new String[] { "name", "type" }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {                  
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>)
lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                 
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.",   
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
    });
}
}
```

EDIT - Fixed unhandled exception, but now it says "No data" when I try to parse the URL.

Thanks again!

Comment: I tried to use logcat, but there's so much data provided I don't know how to sort through it. would you like all of the data?

Comment: The stuff in red (the exception stack dump).

Comment: You want basically the last thing in the log when the app crashes.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the force close but now nothing is getting parsed from the URL. I just receive "no data".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are your mistakes:

`JSONArray  similar = json.getJSONArray("similar");`

1. In parsing JSON you have to note that it's **case sensitive**, i see that your json object is `Similiar` but you try to get it as `similiar`.
2. `Similiar` is a JSON Object but you try to get it as a JSONArray

Here is the fix for your codes, i give you a fix to get `Info` inside `Similiar` object:

```
        JSONObject earthquakes = json.getJSONObject("Similar");
        JSONArray info = earthquakes.getJSONArray("Info");

        for (int i = 0; i < info.length(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject e = info.getJSONObject(i);

            map.put("id", String.valueOf(i));
            map.put("name", "Name:" + e.getString("Name"));
            map.put("type", "Type: " + e.getString("Type"));
            mylist.add(map);
        }
```

Replace your code block inside `try` after `JSONObject json = JSONFun.getJSONfromURL("http://www.tastekid.com/ask/ws?      q=mosdef&f=musifin2125&k=mjjlnzkyzwuz&format=JSON");`
 with code above.

Comment: I checked it on JSONlint and it validated. Where are you seeing the parseResponse() section in my code? I can't see it anywhere.

Comment: eh? it's there when I tried it before, looks like you changed the url on your code? if you're not it's okay then, I figured out some mistakes, i will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

have you added the permission tag in your manifest file which allow the use of internet