# JSON Parsing for Android - nested items?

Tags: android, json, parsing, nested

I have used this site for years, but never have posted. I am stumped and hope someone might be able to help me.

I am using very similar code to what Slicekick posted here [JSON parsing app "no data"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884443/json-parsing-app-no-data/8753557#8753557), but can not seem to figure out how to parse this JSON file. I have edited his JSON info to reflect the exact format I am trying to parse to save space/time. How do I parse the "Results" so I can query "Name" and "Type"? Like his problem with "Similar" and "Info", how do I parse "Info" and "Results" in the file below?

Here is an example of a JSON file edited in the exact format I am using:

```
{
"head": {
    "title": "Music",
    "status": "200"
},
"Info": [
    {
        "Name": "Mos Def",
        "Type": "music",
        "Results": [
            {
                "Name": "Talib Kweli",
                "Type": "music"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Black Star",
                "Type": "music"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Little Brother",
                "Type": "music"
            }
         ]
    }, 
    {
        "Name": "Mos Def",
        "Type": "Vehicles",
        "Results": [
            {
                "Name": "Chevy",
                "Type": "Car"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Ford",
                "Type": "Car"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Pontiac",
                "Type": "Car"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The part of my code that may be of interest is:

... I do a httpget
... that gets built into a StringBuilder
... creates a JSONObject with the results of StringBuilder

```
   jArray = new JSONObject(result);
```

... then returns that

Then onto...

```
   JSONArray  Info = json.optJSONArray("Info");

   System.out.println("HERE IS INFO: ");
   System.out.println(Info);
   //System.out.println("HERE IS RESULTS: ");
   //System.out.println(Results);
```

And basically here is where I am stumped.
I put in print messages to try to narrow the issue down.

Parsing "Info" allows me to search: "Name": "Mos Def" "Type": "music" -and- "Name": "Mos Def" "Type": "Vehicles"

Replacing the search of "Info" with "Results" gives me no data. (Not found)

Any ideas?

Comment: nobody will code for u, u need to do by urself.

Comment: Wasn't looking for a coder. Was looking for a person with a hint or idea to steer me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your parsing code as below:

```
jArray = new JSONObject(result);
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
{
    JSONArray  Info = json.optJSONArray("Info");
    for(int j=0;j<Info.length();j++){
    {
         System.out.println("HERE IS INFO: ");
         System.out.println(Info);
         //System.out.println("HERE IS RESULTS: ");
         JSONObject obj=Info.getJSONObject(j);
         JSONArray results=obj.getJSONArray("Results");
         for(int k=0; k<results.length();
         {
             //Process Results
         }
}
```

Comment: Will this give the output? I don't think so because Results is inside a JSONObject and you are trying to access it directly.

Comment: Yes, it may need some Edition, and I have edited posted accordingly, but still it is not compiled code.

Comment: By reading your response and Lalit's response I was able to put something together that made it work. I thank you so much for taking the time to post! I will post the working solution I ended up with if you think it may help anyone.

Answer (score 4):

That is for sure because `Results` is an JSONArray inside the JSONArray `Info`. So you should try something like this,

```
JSONArray  Info = json.optJSONArray("Info");
JSONArray Results = null;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = Info.getJSONObject(i);
            Results results = object.getJSONArray("Results");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this reply. That is all I really needed was a little hint. By using what you posted & what Jitendra posted - I have now have it figured out. Thanks again! I'll post what eventually got it working if you think it may help anyone else.

Comment: @lalit Bro I am also facing json parsing problem. I have getting JsonException when I create JsonObject, here is the link to my question. (QUESTION)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523805/json-exception-type-mismatch/17523993?noredirect=1#17523993]

Kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

Better use GSON, its from Google and parsing JSON using it is piece of cake..!!
Here is a good tutorial to kick it off, you will be more happy using GSON.

[Link for GSON tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've read up on it and still may check it out soon. Had problems trying to import the jar file for some reason so I moved on (kept trying to figure out the included JSON libraries.)

Comment: download gson from http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list , and once downloaded make a "lib" folder in your droid project and then move it there, after that right click project properties in eclipse and add the library, that's it!